# Click one class with string name to activate another class

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following code which works like - when you click on a random letter (which has a class name assigned to it by a string) display another class in a different container but with the same name as it.

An example would be
A B C D E F G H I J K L M N O P Q R S T U V W X Y Z

F O O T B A L L

clicking A from the aplhabet changes the visibility of A in the word football
Here's the code:

```
$('.answer, .answer2, .answer3').click(function(){
    answer.push($(this).data("value"));                                             //push clicked to array
    checkString = answer.toString();                                                //convert to string
    checkAnswer = checkString.split("");                                            //split string
    console.log(answer);                                                            //display the answer in console
    $('#page1').hide();                                                             //hide page 1
    $('#page2').show().append('<div id="answer"></div>');           //show answer on page, each char needs to be wrapped

    for(var i = 0; i < checkAnswer.length; i++) {
      $('#answer').append('<span class="answer-string ' + checkAnswer[i] + '" data-answer="' + checkAnswer[i] + '">' + checkAnswer[i] + '</span>');   
    }
});


$('#page2').each(function (i) {
    var keyboard = '';
    for(var i = 97; i <= 122; i++) {
        keyboard += '<div class="letter" data-letter="'+String.fromCharCode(i)+'">'+String.fromCharCode(i)+'</div>';
    }
    $(this).append(keyboard);
});

$('.letter').each(function(ev){                                                     //each letter
        $(this).one('click', function(ev){                                              //when clicked
            $(this).css("opacity", "0.8");
            console.log($(this).data("letter"));                                        //log the clicked letter

            if(checkAnswer.indexOf($(this).data("letter"))!=-1) {                       //if clicked letter is in string display success
                $(this).css("background", "rgb(145, 255, 185)");
                console.log("YES");
            }
```

So ideally, if checkAnswerhas an index of the clicked letter, add css to the span class with the same letter as the one clicked, hope that makes sense!

http://jsfiddle.net/xA3YT/ fiddle here, although, ignore the functionality as it's just the way I'm working - Basically, when the letter goes green (or says yes in console log) it should display one of the **`<span>`** (line 16 of script) within **`#answer`**, obviously I know how to activate the CSS but i don't know how to trigger it whether the classes match (it may be something really simple i'm overlooking, im not sure - thanks!)

Comment: Can you create a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/), It will e much easier and faster to find a solution

Comment: Show your html or create jsFiddle testcase.

Comment: @satpal http://jsfiddle.net/xA3YT/ fiddle here, although, ignore the functionality as it's just the way I'm working - Basically, when the letter goes green (or says yes in console log) it should display one of the <span> within #answer, obviously I know how to activate the CSS but i don't know how to trigger it whether the classes match (it may be something really simple i'm overlooking, im not sure - thanks!)

Comment: @antindexer http://jsfiddle.net/xA3YT/ fiddle here, although, ignore the functionality as it's just the way I'm working - Basically, when the letter goes green (or says yes in console log) it should display one of the <span> within #answer, obviously I know how to activate the CSS but i don't know how to trigger it whether the classes match (it may be something really simple i'm overlooking, im not sure - thanks!)

Comment: @AlexNewman there are no `<span>`s in that JSFiddle...

Comment: @Shai they get appended on line 16 in the script

Comment: @AlexNewman my bad! See answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just create a class selector based on the letter that was clicked:

```
$("." + $(this).data("letter")).css('visibility', 'visible');
```

[JSFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/xA3YT/2/) (added this code on line 33)

Comment: Thanks a lot, I just wasn't sure how to get that selector inside the selector as I was always getting invalid identifier errors etc. Thanks man!